# Execute a python function after specific time without using celery

Tags: python, django

I am trying to execute a python function after specific time without using celery. I'm hitting a url using `requests` when `requests` raises any exception then after 60 seconds I execute same function again.

```
def myfun():
    try:
        response = requests.post('url', data=data)
    except Exception as e:
        sleep(60)
        myfun()
```

But this is recursive function and will consume memory. I want to write an async function to execute my task. How can this be done?

Comment: but where does django come into the picture? This is plain python

Answer (score 1):

You can use ayncronous tasks in python multiprocessing. Here is an example

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes

    result = pool.apply_async(f, (10,))   # evaluate "f(10)" asynchronously in a single process
    print result.get(timeout=1)           # prints "100" unless your computer is *very* slow

    print pool.map(f, range(10))          # prints "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"

    it = pool.imap(f, range(10))
    print it.next()                       # prints "0"
    print it.next()                       # prints "1"
    print it.next(timeout=1)              # prints "4" unless your computer is *very* slow

    result = pool.apply_async(time.sleep, (10,))
    print result.get(timeout=1)           # raises multiprocessing.TimeoutError
```

Read full documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html).